Read sensor data while executing another action
I’m new to raspberry and python and I’m  currently building a raspberry 3 wheeled robot that drives and stops via sensor data (ultrasonic sensor HC-SR04) from an arduino. Data is send through the serial port from the arduino.
I tried to tie the received values to the functions forward() and stop() that are then activated by an if statement setting the drive to true or false depending on if the value falls under 20 or not. If I try this code then the bot drives forward but wont read the sensor value anymore making it go forward forever. Maybe my loop is wrong but I haven’t found a fix yet. Here’s my code:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import serial

if __name__ == '__main__':
ser = serial. Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)
ser.flush
# Direction pin from controller
DIR = 17
DIR2 = 24
DIR3 = 6
# step pin, from controller
STEP = 27
STEP2 = 23
STEP3 = 5
#Enablepin Ändern
EN = 22
EN2 = 25
EN3 = 13
# 0/1 used to signify clockwise or counterclockwise.
CW = 1
CCW = 0

#Setup pin layout on PI 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO. BCM)

# Establish Pins in software
GPIO. setup(DIR, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO. setup(STEP, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO. setup(EN, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO. setup(DIR2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO. setup(STEP2, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO. setup(EN2, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO. setup(DIR3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO. setup(STEP3, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO. setup(EN3, GPIO.OUT)
# Set the first direction you want it to spin
GPIO .output (DIR, CW)

drive = False

def forward():
# Esablish the direction you want to e
GPIO. output(DIR, CCW)
GPIO. output(DIR2, CW)
GPIO. output(DIR3, CW)
# Set one coil winding to high
GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(STEP2, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(STEPS, GPIO. HIGH)
# Allow it to get there.
sleep(.000008) # Dictates how fast stepper will run
# Set coil winding to low:
GPIO. output(STEP, GPIO. LOW)
GPIO. output(STEP2, GPIO. LOW)
GPIO. output(STEP, GPIO. LOW)
sleep (.000008) # Dictates how fast stepper will run
return

def stop():
GPIO. output(DIR, CCW)
GPIO. output(DIR2, CW)
GPIO. output(DIR3, CW)
GPIO. output(STEP, GPIO. LOW)
GPIO. output(STEP2, GPIO. LOW)
GPIO. output(STEP, GPIO. LOW)
return

while True:
If ser.in_waiting > 0:
line = ser. readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip('\0')
convert = int(line)
if convert < 20:
stop()
print('stop')
drive = False
else:
drive = True

while drive == true:
forward()

`

you need to fix the indentatoin of your code. Python relies on intentation to determine blocks of code. Your code as is now won't work

Follow to this blog post. You need to use Threading to run multiple functions in the same time. https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Thank you! Threading seems to be the right direction for my code. As for the indentation I’ll fix it while I get the threading to work.

@ArdaYasar Do you have any idea on how I can thread the functions to scan data and drive at the same time? I've tried to thread them but its not really working. Thank you for your help in advance!
